# Exception error in Java

Tags: java, exception, awt

I created a java program that will convert decimal to binary and vice versa. I don't have any problems with my decimal to binary. But when I coded my binary to decimal I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at converter.actionPerformed(converter.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class converter  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField txt1;
    JTextField txt2;
    JLabel lbl1;
    JLabel lbl2;
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;

    public converter(){
        Container c = getContentPane();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        c.add(jp);
        jp.add(lbl1=new JLabel("Decimal: "));
        jp.add(txt1=new JTextField(10));
        jp.add(lbl2=new JLabel("Binary: "));
        jp.add(txt2=new JTextField(10));
        jp.add(b1=new JButton("Convert"));
        jp.add(b2=new JButton("Clear"));
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        converter cvt = new converter();
        cvt.setResizable(false);
        cvt.setVisible(true);
        cvt.setSize(250,150);
        cvt.setTitle("Decimal - Binary Converter");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String num = txt1.getText();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(num);
        if(txt1 != null && e.getSource() == b1){
            String z = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            txt2.setText(z);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == b2){
            txt1.setText("");
            txt2.setText("");
        }
        else if(txt2 != null && e.getSource() == b1){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().trim(), 2);
            txt1.setText(""+x);
        }
    }

}
```

Can you point out what is wrong? And what can be its solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any bounds checking in your code. Aka, you have two text inputs and one 'Convert' function, but the function is applicable for all the following combinations:

- Decimal input and Binary input are both given
- Decimal input and Binary input are both omitted
- Decimal input is given, Binary input is omitted
- Decimal input is omitted, Binary input is given

You need to decide what to do in all four cases, and then proceed with your parse appropriately. Three out of four of these cases are pretty straightforward to deal with - leaving you with having to make a decision about what to do when a user fills in both the Decimal and Binary input fields then hits Convert (I would recommend showing an error dialog in that case).

As it stands, you are parsing your Decimal input field in all cases, and when its left blank this translates to:

```
Integer.parseInt("")
```

Which throws a `NumberFormatException`, as expected.

---

I would handle your four possible scenarios something like this:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String str) {
    return (str == null || str.trim().equals(""));
}

final String decimalInput = text1.getText();
final String binaryInput = text2.getText();

if(! isEmpty(decimalInput)) {
    if( ! isEmpty(binaryInput)) {
        // Decimal input and Binary input are both given, show error
    } else {
        // Decimal input is given, Binary input is omitted, convert to binary
    }
} else {
    if( isEmpty(binaryInput)) {
        // Decimal input and Binary input are both omitted, show error
    } else {
        // Decimal input is omitted, Binary input is given, convert to decimal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `txt1` and `txt2` value if it's a number or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the trace shows that there is an error thrown when your program tries to convert an empty string (`""`) to an `int`. If you look further down the trace (on line 5), the error occurs in the `actionPerformed` method. Particularly, the lines:

```
String num = txt1.getText();
int i = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

You could solve this problems by first checking if the string is not empty with:

```
if (num.length() < 1)
  // tell user they must enter a number
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things jump to mind.

You could trap the exception and display a message telling the user that the value they entered is invalid.  You should also `trim` the result from the field just to be sure.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {      
        String num = txt1.getText().trim(); // <-- Trim the incoming value
        int i = Integer.parseInt(num);
        if(txt1 != null && e.getSource() == b1){
            String z = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            txt2.setText(z);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == b2){
            txt1.setText("");
            txt2.setText("");
        }
        // I'm not sure if this a logic error or not, but txt2 is text field...
        // Did you think it was the text from the field??
        else if(txt2 != null && e.getSource() == b1){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().trim(), 2);
            txt1.setText(""+x);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        // Display message...
    }
}
```

The other is to use a `DocumentFilter` to prevent the user from entering any values that are invalid for the fields.

Check out [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

**Updated**

You also have some logic errors...

`txt1` and `txt2` are never likely to be `null`, unless you've done something horrible wrong...

You should check to see what button was pressed first, that will allow you to make a clearer decision on how to progress.

You should then check the text from the fields and decide on which conversion path you want to go on...

```
try {
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
        String dec = txt1.getText();
        String bin = txt2.getText();

        if (dec != null && dec.trim().length() > 0 &&
            bin != null && bin.trim().length() > 0) {
            // Both fields are filled out?!
        } else if (dec != null && dec.trim().length() > 0) {
            String value = txt1.getText();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(dec);
            String z = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            txt2.setText(z);
        } else if (bin != null && bin.trim().length() > 0) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
            txt1.setText("" + x);
        }
    } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        txt1.setText("");
        txt2.setText("");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and the error didn't show up. But my problem is, when I input a binary number in my txt2 field, txt1 is not displaying the decimal value.

Comment: You also have some logic problems (and my `try-catch` is a little wide) - check update